# How to determine which key triggered RoutedCommand event

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to support several shortcut keys in my application. If I use the construction, see the attached code, ie insert more gestures into one InputGestures, it works - both keyboard shortcuts call the function, but how do I recognize which of the possible key combinations it was?

```
RoutedCommand myCmd = new RoutedCommand();
myCmd.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.A, ModifierKeys.Control));
myCmd.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.B, ModifierKeys.Control));
CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(myCmd, CtrlKeyPressed));

void CtrlKeyPressed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
   if(Key.A ..do something ?
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Keyboard.IsKeyDown` method to determine which keys that were pressed:

```
private void CtrlKeyPressed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CTRL+A");
        }
        else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.B))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CTRL+B");
        }
    }
}
```

Or simply add two different command bindings.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping that the information could be in ExecutedRoutedEventArgs - but I was not able to find it there. However, mm8, both of your suggestions look good.